# Cant start multiple Rabbitmq instance in single machine

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing

I am try to setup a rabbitmq cluster in my Mac OS X 10.11.6(single machine).

It is fail for me to start a second instance of rabbitmq even i try ways on internet. what command i used is following:

> export RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5672
>
> export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
>
> rabbitmq-server -detached
>
> export RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673
>
> export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit2@localhost
>
> rabbitmq-server -detached

Only the first instance can be started.

here's the error_log from rabbitmq and i save it to github:
[link for error log](https://github.com/kazexd/rabbitmq_error_log/blob/master/rabbit2%40localhost.log)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the AMQP port (5672). RabbitMQ also binds the port 15672 for the management API. In the error log you can see that the two instances of rabbitMQ are trying to bind that same port, so you have to bind a different management port in each instance